# Outputing numbers in several data types to MessageBox creates a mess

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, masm, masm32

I am trying to output decimals (int and floats) in almost all datatypes from `byte` to `real10` line by line in MB, but for some reason almost none of them are displayed correctly (image below), most of them are broken, can someone explain why is that happening and what is my mistake?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
titletext db  'Title',0
frmt db  'A (Byte) = %d',10
     db  '-A (Byte) = %d',10
     db  'A (Word) = %d',10
     db  'B (Word) = %d',10
     db  '-A (Word) = %d',10
     db  '-B (Word) = %d',10
     db  'A (ShortInt) = %d',10
     db  'B (ShortInt) = %d',10
     db  'C (ShortInt) = %d',10
     db  '-A (ShortInt) = %d',10
     db  '-B (ShortInt) = %d',10
     db  '-C (ShortInt) = %d',10
     db  'A (LongInt) = %d',10
     db  'B (LongInt) = %d',10
     db  'C (LongInt) = %d',10
     db  '-A (LongInt) = %d',10
     db  '-B (LongInt) = %d',10
     db  '-C (LongInt) = %d',10
     db  'D (Single) = %g',10
     db  '-D (Single) = %g',10
     db  'E (Double) = %g',10
     db  '-E (Double) = %g',10
     db  'F (Extended) = %g',10
     db  '-F (Extended) = %g',0

buff db 1024 dup (?)

Abyte db 6
nAbyte db -6
Aword dw 6
Bword dw 603
nAword dw -6
nBword dw -603
Ashort dd 6
Bshort dd 603
Cshort dd 6032000
nAshort dd -6
nBshort dd -603
nCshort dd -6032000
Along dq 6
Blong dq 603
Clong dq 6032000
nAlong dq -6
nBlong dq -603
nClong dq -6032000
Dsingle real4 0.001
nDsingle real4 -0.001
Edouble real8 0.074
nEdouble real8 -0.074
Fextended real10 735.430
nFextended real10 -735.430

.code
start:
   invoke  crt_sprintf, addr buff, addr frmt,
      Abyte, nAbyte,
      Aword, Bword, nAword, nBword,
      Ashort, Bshort, Cshort, nAshort,nBshort, nCshort,
      Along, Blong, Clong, nAlong, nBlong, nClong,
      Dsingle, nDsingle,
      Edouble, nEdouble,
      Fextended, nFextended
   invoke  MessageBox, 0, addr buff, addr titletext, MB_OK
   invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

current result:

[image: current result]

Comment: You're using a `%d` conversion for narrow args that you aren't promoting to `int`.  They might contain high garbage if MASM's `invoke` doesn't magically sign- or zero-extend them for you.  Also, `short` is normally a 16-bit byte but you're using `dd`.  That shouldn't matter in this case since 32-bit code always uses 32-bit stack slots at minimum for arg-passing.  Speaking of which, look at how that `invoke` assembles, and look at stack memory after whatever it does, to see if your args are being passed correctly.

Comment: Also, the floats are all broken because you forgot to apply the C default promotions of float to double that always happens for args to the `...` part of a variadic function.  [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082784).  So your 4-byte floats skew everything later.

Comment: Oh, similarly, you have some `dq` 64-bit integers but you're still telling sprintf they're `%d` `int`.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you! also wanted to ask how much buffersize do you really usually need?

Comment: Uh, as long as your string could possibly ever be, with worst case for all conversions I guess.  Otherwise use `snprintf`, and check the return value and allocate more space if needed.  If you just reserve space on the stack, instead of static storage, it's fine in a function that's part of a larger program.  You aren't tying up that extra memory permanently.  (Generally only do big stack allocations in leaf functions, though; if you do it all over the place and then call more functions you could use up all your stack space.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I've changed all `byte`, `word` and `dword` to signed types and it worked well, but I am having trouble with `qword` and `real4`. I changed `%d` for `%ld` for qword, but it still puts `0` to the next entry, shifting all numbers after it. And about floats, as I understood from the link to the other thread you posted - it is impossible to print out a float, I need to convert it to different type somehow? Sorry if I am understanding it badly.

Comment: In 32-bit ABIs, `long` is still a 32-bit type.  You probably need `long long`.  And you simply can't use `invoke` with a `real4` for a printf-like function.  [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082784).  Look at compiler-generated code for the equivalent C. You'll have to convert your real10 and real4 to `double` and push them manually, before invoke.  (Your [libc probably uses `long double` = `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60887766) (see comments), not the 10-byte x87 type.  So there's probably no way to get that sprintf to handle a tbyte.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your format string doesn't match what you're getting `invoke` to pass.**

You're using a `%d` conversion for narrow args that you aren't promoting to `int`.  `%hhd` and `%hd` respectively are the conversions you want for `int8_t` (signed char as an integer) and `int16_t` (`short`).  ISO C doesn't specify that short = int16_t, but that is the case on 32-bit Windows.

Anyway, the high bytes of those 4-byte stack slots for passing those narrow integers might contain high garbage if MASM's `invoke` doesn't magically sign- or zero-extend them for you.

Also, `short` is normally a 16-bit byte but you're using `dd`. That shouldn't matter in this case since 32-bit code always uses 32-bit stack slots at minimum for arg-passing.

**To further debug this yourself:**  Look at how that invoke directive or macro actually assembles to real machine instructions.  i.e. disassemble the resulting code, to see what it's really doing.  (Or use a debugger with disassembly view to single-step).  Also **use a debugger to look at stack memory** after each step, before the `call`, to see if your args are being passed correctly.

If you aren't sure what the right sequence of asm instructions you need is, look at compiler output from a C or C++ compiler for equivalent code that calls sprintf with C global variables of the same types you want.  (e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ which has 32-bit x86 MSVC available.  Its calling convention and type widths should be the ones `crt_sprintf` is expecting, that you're linking via MASM32.)

---

**Also, the floats are all broken because you forgot to apply the C default promotions of float to double** that always happens for args to the `...` part of a variadic function. [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082784)  So your 4-byte floats skew everything later.

And similarly, you have some `dq` 64-bit integers but you're still telling sprintf they're `%d` (int).  So you actually get the high and low halves of a `dq` being read by two separate `%d` conversions, leading to the wrong conversion reading the wrong bytes.

---

> I've changed all `byte`, `word` and `dword` to signed types and it worked well, but I am having trouble with `qword` and `real4`. I changed `%d` for `%ld` for `qword`, but it still puts 0 to the next entry, shifting all numbers after it.

In 32-bit ABIs, `long` is still a 32-bit type.  You need `long long` and **the conversion for that is `%lld` for `dq`.**

> And about floats, as I understood from the link to the other thread you posted - it is impossible to print out a float, I need to convert it to different type somehow?

That's correct.  You simply can't use `invoke` with a `real4` for a printf-like functions that take their arg via a `...` part of a C variadic function.

Look at compiler-generated code for the equivalent C.

You'll have to convert your `real4` to `double` and push them manually, before invoke.  (Invoke pushes in right-to-left order, last args pushed first, so you can do those pushes and then use `invoke` I guess?)

Also [your libc probably uses `long double` = `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60887766) (see comments on that answer), not the 10-byte x87 type.  So there's probably no way to get that sprintf to handle a tbyte and you'll have to convert it to `double` as well.  Or just don't bother using `real10` unless you find a C library that can handle it.

(Oh, it was you that asked that question.  It's still the same problem.)